# Exact functionality of Java garbage collection

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, tree, garbage-collection

I'm pretty new to Java, and I know there have been a lot of questions dealing with garbage collection in Java on this site, so I expect to get downvoted - but I haven't found an answer that clearly addresses my particular situation.

I'm building a 2-3 tree in Java. Each node of the 2-3 tree contains references to the heads of linear linked lists of a custom type, meaning those are dynamically allocated as well.

Basically:

```
          A           <-- my root reference
     /         \
   B,C          D
 /  |  \       /   \
E   F   G     H     I
                   /
                  J
```

Where each letter represents the head reference of a linked list of more dynamically-created objects.

Am I correct in assuming that setting the root reference to null makes the entire tree, and all of the objects in all of the linear linked lists, eligible for garbage collection? Or is there something else I need to do to prevent a memory leak?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. However, you don't need to `null` `A` explicitly. All that is necessary is that `A` no longer be reachable. There is no guarantee when (or if) the GC will actually occur.

Comment: Thank you. I take it that a reference going out of scope also makes the object eligible for GC (assuming that object is not elsewhere referenced).

Comment: Precisely that. See also [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html). And [reachability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability).

Comment: There's an exception - if you've got any interned Strings, they won't get deallocated, so this is one way to create a memory leak.  But other than that, the answer to your question is found in Elliott's comment.

Comment: Also note that the entire tree's objects are only eligible for garbage collection provided there aren't other references apart from this tree. So if `A` is no longer referenced, but if you hold the reference of `I` somewhere, then all contents of `I` and `J` remains non-garbage-collectible.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I guess, you're wrong: http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/ "String pool values are garbage collected".